# mysql replica ignoring server-id

Tags: mysql, replication

I've setup a mysql replica slave a couple months ago. After a couple hickups lately, I've decide to restore it from a clean master export.

I'm trying to start my mysql instance with this command :

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my_secondary.cnf --server-id=2 --log-bin --skip-slave-start --skip-name-resolve&
```

I've declared the server-id in my cnf file as the following :

```
server-id = 2
```

But when I connect with the command line client, and I check the variable, I get :

```
mysql> show variables like "version";
+---------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                   |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| server-id     | 0                       |
+---------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm also getting the feeling that my instance is ignoring my "CHANGE MASTER" commands since it's complaining each time i run "start slave", but I would like to settle this server-id issue first.

I'm running two instance of Mysql 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 (one on port 3306, and this one on 4306)

Comment: Can you paste the output to `\s` I suspect that you are changing this variable on server on 4306 and connection to server running on 3306

Comment: you were right, I checked the port variable and I was indeed sending my commands to the wrong instance. Can you post an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we suspected, you are making the changes on 4306 and connecting on default port which is the server running on 3306. use these :

```
mysql -u user -p --port 4306
```